# memcpy flagged for buffer overflow

Tags: c++, static-analysis, buffer-overflow

I am running a static security analyzer on some old `C++` code.  It is flagging the `::memcpy` call as a buffer overflow violation.  The code looks fine to me.  Why is it complaining?

```
#define ALLOC_SIZE 4 * 1024

int arr_max = ALLOC_SIZE;
int *arr = new int[arr_max];    

// ...

void resize_arr() {
  int* new_arr = new int[arr_max + ALLOC_SIZE];
  ::memcpy(new_arr, arr, arr_max * sizeof(int)); // BUFFER OVERFLOW
  arr_max += ALLOC_SIZE;    
  delete [] arr;
  arr = new_arr;
}
```

Comment: `arr_max * sizeof(int)` is a few times greater than arr_max.. Maybe that's why it's complaining?

Comment: @Jacek, arr_max is a count of the number of `ints`. The last parameter to memcpy is the number of `bytes`

Comment: `int[] arr = new int[arr_max]; ` shouldn't even compile, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: maybe it is not sure if `new_arr` is at least as big as `arr`, like what if you did `int* new_arr = new int[something_smaller_than_arr_max];`

Comment: Fails on VC 19 too https://godbolt.org/g/ZnhVLF, are you sure this is the exact code you are compiling?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to simplify the code for SO and did it badly... I corrected the `arr` declaration from an array to a pointer

Comment: `arr_max * sizeof(int)` probably evaluates to 16384 and `arr_max` (number of ints) is 8192.  `int` is probably 4 bytes so whoops it looks like an overflow.

Comment: @JustinRandall, remember, `memcpy` takes number of bytes, not number of ints

Comment: Right yes thank you. So you're telling it to copy 16384 bytes from `arr` (all of it) into `new_arr` which is sized to 32768 bytes and should fit. Seems like a false positive.

Comment: Static analyzers tend to suck at this.  Fortify for example gets this wrong all the time.  Just suppress the diagnostic or go shopping for a better one.

Comment: Yeah it's Fortify :) Any ideas how to satisfy Fortify instead of suppressing it? There is "compliance" red tape involved in suppressing these warnings :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how clever your code analyzer is but if you make enough cosequantial calls to `resize_arr` function the `arr_max` will eventually overflow and might cause buffer overflow.